# Android oAuth for Uber API - SSO hangs with INVALID_APP_SIGNATURE

Tags: android, uber-api

Objective: Use Uber API SSO to login, retrieve authorization token, store auth token in TokenManager. But first, I'd be happy with just getting the token. 
Assumption: My app will run on Androids with the Uber app installed.

Given the objective and assumption - I believe I do not need a "Backend" is that correct? Once I get the auth token I will just use that via SSO to request rides.

I posted my code below. Please help. (I commented out the onResume code because, for now, I am just trying to get the initial login working.) My code was based largely on Uber provided Samples [here](https://github.com/uber/rides-android-sdk/tree/master/samples)

I have an Uber API client ID because I populated the Uber Developer site [here](https://developer.uber.com/dashboard/) Also I posted my AndroidDebug hashkey to this site.

My phone has Uber installed on it.

When I run the app below on my phone (not emulator) and tap button, sometimes the black Uber-logo app screen comes up, turns to white and hangs indefinitely. 
Sometimes a white screen comes up saying there was a problem connecting. When I press the UBer-presented "Okay" button the Uber screen reverts back to my app. My app traps the error (see onLoginError) and Toasts it as "INVALID_APP_SIGNATURE" Running Android Studio I am unable to trap the return with a break point. The BP is set but it never fires.

BTW I know at least part of my Uber API credentials are correct. I have used Postman to request a token and also providing scope=request and I get the token. However, I recognize doing it via Postman is likely not hitting Uber API SSO.

Based on my reading, the error string above, and the way the app is reacting, this looks like a openSSL/hash/key problem but my hashkey works for Facebook logins.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mGoButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.goBtn);

    configuration = new SessionConfiguration.Builder()
            .setClientId(CLIENT_ID)
            .setRedirectUri(REDIRECT_URI)
            .setScopes(Arrays.asList(Scope.RIDE_WIDGETS, Scope.REQUEST, Scope.PROFILE))
            .setEnvironment(SessionConfiguration.Environment.PRODUCTION)
            //.setEnvironment(SessionConfiguration.Environment.SANDBOX)
            .build();

    accessTokenStorage = new AccessTokenManager(getApplicationContext());
    accessTokenManager = new AccessTokenManager(getApplicationContext());
    Long expirationTime = 2592000L;
    List<Scope> scopes = Arrays.asList(Scope.RIDE_WIDGETS);
    String token = "obtainedAccessToken";
    String refreshToken = "obtainedRefreshToken";
    String tokenType = "obtainedTokenType";
    accessToken = new AccessToken(expirationTime, scopes, token, refreshToken, tokenType);
    accessTokenStorage.setAccessToken(accessToken);

    //Use a custom button with an onClickListener to call the LoginManager directly
    loginManager = new LoginManager(accessTokenManager,
            new SampleLoginCallback(),
            configuration,
            CUSTOM_BUTTON_REQUEST_CODE);

    loginManager.setRedirectForAuthorizationCode(true);

    mGoButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            loginManager.login(MainActivity.this);
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    //if (loginManager.isAuthenticated()) {
    //    loadProfileInfo();
    //}
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    Log.i(LOG_TAG, String.format("onActivityResult requestCode:[%s] resultCode [%s]",
            requestCode, resultCode));
    loginManager.onActivityResult(this, requestCode, resultCode, data);
}

private class SampleLoginCallback implements LoginCallback {

    @Override
    public void onLoginCancel() {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, R.string.user_cancels_message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    @Override
    public void onLoginError(@NonNull AuthenticationError error) {
        int a = 1;
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                    getString(R.string.login_error_message, error.name()), Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
        }
    @Override
    public void onLoginSuccess(@NonNull AccessToken accessToken) {
        loadProfileInfo();
    }
    @Override
    public void onAuthorizationCodeReceived(@NonNull String authorizationCode) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, getString(R.string.authorization_code_message, authorizationCode),
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
            .show();
    }
}
```

Sasa when I copy / paste your code in my environment (Android Studio) I get the red line / error below because it changes the first parameter in the LoginManger call to tokenStorage vs tokenManager. The IDE calls the error a mismatch between required and provided parameters.

[image]

And here is my build gradle

[image]

Comment: Did you generated your signing certificate hash by running following command:
keytool -exportcert -alias <your_key_alias> -keystore <your_keystore_path> | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64 ?
Also have you updated your Security "App Signatures" box with that generated key? From your question I see you have some kind of hashkey - just wanted to make sure you used "keytool" to get it generated.

Comment: Thanks. My key ends with an = sign. Yes I used keytool -exportcert -alias yyyyy -keystore C:\Users\xxxxx | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64. I did this with both my androiddebug key and a recently generated release key. Both keys produced the same result. Also I have Facebook oAuth working with the AndroidDebugKey. Not sure why Uber is not working with the same key.  Any help you can lend is appreciated. I have been working on this for 2 weeks.

Comment: What is your application name in: https://developer.uber.com/dashboard? I can get all required info based on this - it is safe for you to post it here.

Comment: Thanks it is:             TestAppFour

Answer (score 1):

I managed to reproduce your issue. Problem is definitely with the generation of the hash of your signing certificate.

To get the hash of your signing certificate, run this command with the alias of your key and path to your key store:

> keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore
>   ~/.android/debug.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64

By default the debug keystore has a blank password.

Also not sure why you have two AccessTokenManager instances. Your code should look like:

```
configuration = new SessionConfiguration.Builder()
            .setClientId(CLIENT_ID)
            .setRedirectUri(REDIRECT_URI)
            .setScopes(Arrays.asList(Scope.RIDE_WIDGETS, Scope.REQUEST, Scope.PROFILE))
            .setEnvironment(SessionConfiguration.Environment.PRODUCTION)
            //.setEnvironment(SessionConfiguration.Environment.SANDBOX)
            .build();

accessTokenStorage = new AccessTokenManager(this);
loginManager = new LoginManager(accessTokenStorage,
            new SampleLoginCallback(),
            configuration,
            CUSTOM_BUTTON_REQUEST_CODE);

    loginManager.setRedirectForAuthorizationCode(true);

    customButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.custom_uber_button);
    customButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            loginManager.login(LoginSampleActivity.this);
        }
    });
```

I added new button "Test Login" - wich executes above code - and it is going to the Scope Authorization page - and completes authentication.

[image]

[image]

Build gradle file of the login-sample application looks like:

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    google()
}

dependencies {
    classpath deps.build.gradlePlugins.android
}
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion deps.build.compileSdkVersion
buildToolsVersion deps.build.buildToolsVersion

defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion deps.build.minSdkVersion
    targetSdkVersion deps.build.targetSdkVersion
    buildConfigField "String", "CLIENT_ID", "\"${loadSecret("UBER_CLIENT_ID")}\"" //Add your client id to gradle.properties
    buildConfigField "String", "REDIRECT_URI", "\"${loadSecret("UBER_REDIRECT_URI")}\"" //Add your redirect uri to gradle.properties
}
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
}
}

dependencies {
compile project(':rides-android')
compile deps.support.appCompat
}

/**
* Loads property from gradle.properties and ~/.gradle/gradle.properties
* Use to look up confidential information like keys that shoudln't be stored publicly
* @param name to lookup
* @return the value of the property or "MISSING"
*/
def loadSecret(String name) {
return hasProperty(name) ? getProperty(name) : "MISSING"
}
```

Comment: Thanks. 1) I ran the keytool syntax exactly as you provided and got a new key/hash.No password requested/provided 2) I pasted the hash in the Uber API Dev page under Settings, Security, App Signatures. I pressed the Save button 3) I modified my code as you provided above but I just used the button I already had on the layout (goBtn) 4) I ran the app on my phone - same result, black Uber screen comes up with logo only, then transitions to white screen, then hangs indefinitely. It does seem like a key/hash problem but I don't know what else to do? I really want to get this working.

Comment: I even tried shutting off wifi on my phone, just in case. Running with cellular only had the same result.

Comment: Another thing, I have always had this warning upon build "Warning:WARNING: Dependency org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.0.1 is ignored for debug as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android." When I first put the Uber lib in my gradle I could not compile. I found that if I add the following exclude it works.
    compile 'com.uber.sdk:rides-android:0.5.3'    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
        exclude group: 'com.google.code.findbugs'})

Comment: But I still get the warning above. I don't think this is causing my hash problem but wanted to get everything out there.

Comment: Can you share your build gradle file?

Comment: Sure will post it now - but this is the latest one from the Git repository.

Comment: Thanks if possible please take a look at the screen shot and comments from the IDE I appended to the original post above regarding the tokenStorage vs tokenManager.

Comment: Can you download the latest version of the https://github.com/uber/rides-android-sdk and start from there. Looks like this is the problem. I added my build gradle to the answer - of the login-sample module.

Comment: I downloaded rides-android-sdk-master.zip from the link you provided, thanks. I loaded this into Android Studio, I updated client-ID and redirect-URI so they matched Uber Dev. I reran the keytool to confirm the hash was the same (it was).  I built the uber android project successfully with no errors. I then ran login-sample on my phone. Same error.

Comment: Could it be the Uber App?

Comment: I mean could it be the version of the Uber App I have installed?

Comment: Can you try to update to the latest Uber app as well - it could be the reason.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163280/discussion-between-sasa-jovanovic-and-frank-zappa).